# Отключается автоматическое воспроизведение слайдов после щелчка по пункту навигации

Tags: jquery, slider

Поставил слайдер на сайт: работает прекрасно, слайды меняются автоматом, все адаптивное, но есть одна проблемка. В нижней части слайдера размещены кнопки для перехода между разными слайдами и вот при щелчке по любой из них слайды перестают автоматически прокручиваться. Вот как это исправить?
Пример вызова на странице:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var jmpressOpts = {
        animation       : { transitionDuration : '0.8s' }
    };

    $( '#jms-slideshow' ).jmslideshow( $.extend( true, { jmpressOpts : jmpressOpts }, {
        autoplay    : true,
        bgColorSpeed: '0.8s',
        arrows      : false,
    }));

});
```

Сам скрипт

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

/*
 * JMSlideshow object
 */
$.JMSlideshow               = function( options, element ) {

    // the jms-slideshow
    this.$el    = $( element );

    this._init( options );

};

$.JMSlideshow.defaults      = {
    // options for the jmpress plugin.
    // you can add much more options here. Check http://shama.github.com/jmpress.js/
    jmpressOpts : {
        // set the viewport
        viewPort        : {
            height  : 400,
            width   : 1000,
            maxScale: 1
        },
        fullscreen      : false,
        hash            : { use : false },
        mouse           : { clickSelects : false },
        keyboard        : { use : false },
        animation       : { transitionDuration : '6s' }
    },
    // for this specific plugin we will have the following options:
    // shows/hides navigation arrows
    arrows      : true,
    // shows/hides navigation dots/pages
    dots        : true,
    // each step's bgcolor transition speed
    bgColorSpeed: '6s',
    // slideshow on / off
    autoplay    : true,
    // time between transitions for the slideshow
    interval    : 5000
};

$.JMSlideshow.prototype     = {
    _init               : function( options ) {

        this.options        = $.extend( true, {}, $.JMSlideshow.defaults, options );

        // each one of the slides
        this.$slides        = $('#jms-slideshow').children('div');
        // total number of slides
        this.slidesCount    = this.$slides.length;
        // step's bgcolor
        this.colors         = $.map( this.$slides, function( el, i ) { return $( el ).data( 'color' ); } ).join( ' ' );
        // build the necessary structure to run jmpress
        this._layout();
        // initialize the jmpress plugin
        this._initImpress();
        // if support (function implemented in jmpress plugin)
        if( this.support ) {

            // load some events
            this._loadEvents();
            // if autoplay is true start the slideshow
            if( this.options.autoplay ) {

                this._startSlideshow();

            }

        }

    },
    // wraps all the slides in the jms-wrapper div;
    // adds the navigation options ( arrows and dots ) if set to true
    _layout             : function() {

        // adds a specific class to each one of the steps
        this.$slides.each( function( i ) {

            $(this).addClass( 'jmstep' + ( i + 1 ) );

        } );

        // wrap the slides. This wrapper will be the element on which we will call the jmpress plugin
        this.$jmsWrapper    = this.$slides.wrapAll( '<div class="jms-wrapper"/>' ).parent();

        // transition speed for the wrapper bgcolor 
        this.$jmsWrapper.css( {
            '-webkit-transition-duration'   : this.options.bgColorSpeed,
            '-moz-transition-duration'      : this.options.bgColorSpeed,
            '-ms-transition-duration'       : this.options.bgColorSpeed,
            '-o-transition-duration'        : this.options.bgColorSpeed,
            'transition-duration'           : this.options.bgColorSpeed
        } );

        // add navigation arrows
        if( this.options.arrows ) {

            this.$arrows    = $( '<nav class="jms-arrows"></nav>' );

            if( this.slidesCount > 1 ) {

                this.$arrowPrev = $( '<span class="jms-arrows-prev"/>' ).appendTo( this.$arrows );
                this.$arrowNext = $( '<span class="jms-arrows-next"/>' ).appendTo( this.$arrows );

            }

            this.$el.append( this.$arrows )

        }

        // add navigation dots
        if( this.options.dots ) {

            this.$dots      = $( '<nav class="jms-dots"></nav>' );

            for( var i = this.slidesCount + 1; --i; ) {

                this.$dots.append( ( i === this.slidesCount ) ? '<span class="jms-dots-current"/>' : '<span/>' );

            }

            if( this.options.jmpressOpts.start ) {

                this.$start     = this.$jmsWrapper.find( this.options.jmpressOpts.start ), idxSelected = 0;

                ( this.$start.length ) ? idxSelected = this.$start.index() : this.options.jmpressOpts.start = null;

                this.$dots.children().removeClass( 'jms-dots-current' ).eq( idxSelected ).addClass( 'jms-dots-current' );

            }

            this.$el.append( this.$dots )

        }

    },
    // initialize the jmpress plugin
    _initImpress        : function() {

        var _self = this;

        this.$jmsWrapper.jmpress( this.options.jmpressOpts );
        // check if supported (function from jmpress.js):
        // it adds the class not-suported to the wrapper
        this.support    = !this.$jmsWrapper.hasClass( 'not-supported' );

        // if not supported remove unnecessary elements
        if( !this.support ) {

            if( this.$arrows ) {

                this.$arrows.remove();

            }

            if( this.$dots ) {

                this.$dots.remove();

            }

            return false;

        }

        // redefine the jmpress setActive method
        this.$jmsWrapper.jmpress( 'setActive', function( slide, eventData ) {

            // change the pagination dot active class           
            if( _self.options.dots ) {

                // adds the current class to the current dot/page
                _self.$dots
                     .children()
                     .removeClass( 'jms-dots-current' )
                     .eq( slide.index() )
                     .addClass( 'jms-dots-current' );

            }

            // delete all current bg colors
            this.removeClass( _self.colors );
            // add bg color class
            this.addClass( slide.data( 'color' ) );

        } );

        // add step's bg color to the wrapper
        this.$jmsWrapper.addClass( this.$jmsWrapper.jmpress('active').data( 'color' ) );

    },
    // start slideshow if autoplay is true
    _startSlideshow     : function() {

        var _self   = this;

        this.slideshow  = setTimeout( function() {

            _self.$jmsWrapper.jmpress( 'next' );

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                _self._startSlideshow();

            }

        }, this.options.interval );

    },
    // stops the slideshow
    _stopSlideshow      : function() {

        if( this.options.autoplay ) {

            clearTimeout( this.slideshow );
            this.options.autoplay   = false;

        }

    },
    _loadEvents         : function() {

        var _self = this;

        // navigation arrows
        if( this.$arrowPrev && this.$arrowNext ) {

            this.$arrowPrev.on( 'click.jmslideshow', function( event ) {

                _self._stopSlideshow();

                _self.$jmsWrapper.jmpress( 'prev' );

                return false;

            } );

            this.$arrowNext.on( 'click.jmslideshow', function( event ) {

                _self._stopSlideshow();

                _self.$jmsWrapper.jmpress( 'next' );

                return false;

            } );

        }

        // navigation dots
        if( this.$dots ) {

            this.$dots.children().on( 'click.jmslideshow', function( event ) {

                _self._stopSlideshow();

                _self.$jmsWrapper.jmpress( 'goTo', '.jmstep' + ( $(this).index() + 1 ) );

                return false;

            } );

        }

        // the touchend event is already defined in the jmpress plugin.
        // we just need to make sure the slideshow stops if the event is triggered
        this.$jmsWrapper.on( 'touchend.jmslideshow', function() {

            _self._stopSlideshow();

        } );

    }
};

var logError            = function( message ) {
    if ( this.console ) {
        console.error( message );
    }
};

$.fn.jmslideshow        = function( options ) {

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'jmslideshow' );

            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on jmslideshow prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for jmslideshow instance" );
                return;
            }

            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'jmslideshow' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                $.data( this, 'jmslideshow', new $.JMSlideshow( options, this ) );
            }
        });

    }

    return this;

};

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Вопрос снят. Помогли на другом форму. Вот решение: заменить if( this.options.autoplay ) {
this._startSlideshow();
 } на if (this.options.autoplay) {
    this._startSlideshow();
    var _self = this;
    this.$el.mouseleave(function() {
        if (!_self.options.autoplay) {
            _self.options.autoplay = true;
            _self._startSlideshow();
        }
    });
}

Comment: Сделайте самоответ, иначе ваш вопрос потом Дух поднимет на главную